# Azure DevOps ssh script file task

Tags: azure-devops

I'm just wondering if it's possible to use a script file in the SSH task in the Releases that will be populated with the environment variables from azure.

Script:

```
TEST=$(test)
```

I saved this script as an artifact, successfully download it, and select this script in the SSH task as a file, but the problem is the environment variables is not unwrapped, does someone have some approach?

If I put this same script as an inline script, then it's working. But if I chose script file then not.

I want to have this script in the git repo, so I can easily edit the script.

Does someone have this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm just wondering if it's possible to use a script file in the SSH task in the Releases that will be populated with the environment variables from azure

I am afraid there is no such out of way to use a script file in the SSH task to populated with the environment variables from azure.

As workaround,  we could use the task [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to update the value in the script file:

[image]

The format of variable in .sh file is `#{TestVar}#`.

Comment: Hello, your solution seems to work but not completly, unfortunately, i have some $ in those secret variables and those variables are not unwrapped correctly, do you have some fix for that ? otherwise this solution is good with one concern that file being populated not on the target machine only, but in deploy machine

Comment: Ok, i have solution for this:

If you are using shell scripts you need to unwrap the variable in this way if you want to use some dolar signs $ there:

VAR='#{SECRET_VAR}#'

echo $VAR

Thank you for your help, this is good solution.